# How can I add a optimizer for some extra parameters added by me in Transformer?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

[image]
I want to use some of the parameters in the forward() of the BertEncoder defined by the transformer to complete the training of another independent Bertlayer, the approximate flow is shown in the picture.

```
class BertEncoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config, meta_layer_index=None, scale=1):
        super().__init__()
        self.config = config
        self.layer = nn.ModuleList([BertLayer(config) for _ in range(config.num_hidden_layers)])
        self.gradient_checkpointing = False
        self.meta_layer = BertLayer(config) # 
        self.meta_layer_index = meta_layer_index # 
        self.scale = scale # 一层metalayer代表scale层bertlayer
        self.optimizer_for_meta_layer = torch.optim.SGD(self.meta_layer.parameters(), lr=1e-5, weight_decay=0.005)
        self.inputs_for_metalayer = None
        self.outputs_for_metalayer = None
        self.meta_layer_outputs = None
        self.st_loss = None
        
    def forward(
        self,
        hidden_states: torch.Tensor,
        attention_mask: Optional[torch.FloatTensor] = None,
        head_mask: Optional[torch.FloatTensor] = None,
        encoder_hidden_states: Optional[torch.FloatTensor] = None,
        encoder_attention_mask: Optional[torch.FloatTensor] = None,
        past_key_values: Optional[Tuple[Tuple[torch.FloatTensor]]] = None,
        use_cache: Optional[bool] = None,
        output_attentions: Optional[bool] = False,
        output_hidden_states: Optional[bool] = False,
        return_dict: Optional[bool] = True,
    ) -> Union[Tuple[torch.Tensor], BaseModelOutputWithPastAndCrossAttentions]:
        all_hidden_states = () if output_hidden_states else None
        all_self_attentions = () if output_attentions else None
        all_cross_attentions = () if output_attentions and self.config.add_cross_attention else None
        self.inputs_for_metalayer = (hidden_states.clone().detach(), head_mask[0] if head_mask is not None else None, past_key_values[0] if past_key_values is not None else None)
        if self.gradient_checkpointing and self.training:
            if use_cache:
                logger.warning_once(
                    "`use_cache=True` is incompatible with gradient checkpointing. Setting `use_cache=False`..."
                )
                use_cache = False

        next_decoder_cache = () if use_cache else None
        
        # 
        for i, layer_module in enumerate(self.layer):
            if output_hidden_states:
                all_hidden_states = all_hidden_states + (hidden_states,)
            layer_head_mask = head_mask[i] if head_mask is not None else None
            past_key_value = past_key_values[i] if past_key_values is not None else None
            if self.gradient_checkpointing and self.training:

                def create_custom_forward(module):
                    def custom_forward(*inputs):
                        return module(*inputs, past_key_value, output_attentions)

                    return custom_forward

                layer_outputs = torch.utils.checkpoint.checkpoint(
                    create_custom_forward(layer_module),
                    hidden_states,
                    attention_mask,
                    layer_head_mask,
                    encoder_hidden_states,
                    encoder_attention_mask,
                )
            else:
                layer_outputs = layer_module(
                    hidden_states,
                    attention_mask,
                    layer_head_mask,
                    encoder_hidden_states,
                    encoder_attention_mask,
                    past_key_value,
                    output_attentions,
                )
            # layer_outputs : Tuple[torch.Tensor]
            hidden_states = layer_outputs[0]
            # 
            
            if i == self.meta_layer_index - 1:
                self.inputs_for_metalayer = (hidden_states.clone().detach(), layer_head_mask, past_key_value)
            if i == self.meta_layer_index + self.scale - 1:
                self.outputs_for_metalayer = hidden_states.clone().detach()
            if use_cache:
                next_decoder_cache += (layer_outputs[-1],)
            if output_attentions:
                all_self_attentions = all_self_attentions + (layer_outputs[1],)
                if self.config.add_cross_attention:
                    all_cross_attentions = all_cross_attentions + (layer_outputs[2],)
        if self.inputs_for_metalayer is not None and self.outputs_for_metalayer is not None:
            self.meta_layer_outputs = self.meta_layer(
                    self.inputs_for_metalayer[0],
                    attention_mask,
                    self.inputs_for_metalayer[1],
                    encoder_hidden_states,
                    encoder_attention_mask,
                    self.inputs_for_metalayer[2],
                    output_attentions,
                )[0]

            self.st_loss = torch.mean((self.meta_layer_outputs - self.outputs_for_metalayer) ** 2)
            self.optimizer_for_meta_layer.zero_grad()
            self.st_loss.backward()
            self.optimizer_for_meta_layer.step()
            print(list(self.meta_layer.parameters()))
            

            
            
        if output_hidden_states:
            all_hidden_states = all_hidden_states + (hidden_states,)
        if not return_dict:
            return tuple(
                v
                for v in [
                    hidden_states,
                    next_decoder_cache,
                    all_hidden_states,
                    all_self_attentions,
                    all_cross_attentions,
                ]
                if v is not None
            )
        return BaseModelOutputWithPastAndCrossAttentions(
            last_hidden_state=hidden_states,
            past_key_values=next_decoder_cache,
            hidden_states=all_hidden_states,
            attentions=all_self_attentions,
            cross_attentions=all_cross_attentions,
        )
```

I have added my own code to the original, mainly in forward(). The current problem is that print(list(self.meta_layer.parameters())) prints out the parameters when training on a single GPU, but prints null when training on multiple GPUs. When the  logging_steps is reached, the requires_grad of st_loss changes from True to False. I don't know how to solve it.
#pytorch

Comment: Can you clarify your question please. Is your question related to optimizer or is this issue specific to multi gpu training?

Comment: @SajanGohil I think it's specific to multi gpu training. I want to add an optimizer for a specific and independent BertLayer with multi gpu. I need to use trainner defined in Transformers , but I don't know how to modify it.